# How to loop a multiplication?

Tags: php

I want to find vector s. the formula is described in the picture below :

https://s.id/2UZKT (sorry i can't post the image)

the $bb_baru is an array which will be assigned the value in the table.

I've tried to loop, but the `$multiplication_result` variable is undefined.

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $data['jml_alternatif']; $i++) { 
 for ($i=0; $i <= ($this->input->post('iKriteria')-1); $i++) { 
$multiplication_result *= number_format(pow($rangking[$i]['nilai_rangking'], $data['bb_baru'][$i]),4); 
}
$data['vektor_s'][] = $multiplication_result;
}
```

the result of this case according by picture should be :
$vector_s[]=(4.1407,12.2393);

Comment: I think you need to initialize $multiplication_result before the loops

Answer (score 1):

Declare the **$multiplication_result** variable before the second loop.

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $data['jml_alternatif']; $i++) {
    $multiplication_result = 1;

    for ($i=0; $i <= ($this->input->post('iKriteria')-1); $i++) { 
        $multiplication_result *= number_format(pow($rangking[$i]['nilai_rangking'], $data['bb_baru'][$i]), 4); 
    }

    $data['vektor_s'][] = $multiplication_result;
}
```

Comment: okey it' works but the result for alternative 1 slightly missed (the result is 4.1508), and result for alternatif 2 is Undefined offset: 1

Comment: I had a mistake, insert the **$multiplication_result = 1;** inside from first loop (I edited my reply).
Why do you use de same variable $i into both loops?
Into the second loop, the $i variable is rewrited...is it right?